# Viewing Burninated/blacklisted tags

Tags: support, burninate-system

Apologies if this question has already been answered somewhere already.

Is there somewhere I can view a list of tags which have been burninated/blacklisted from certain sites?

UPDATE:

I'm building a script which tags documents with relevant Stackoverflow tags. I was seeking a way of excluding at least *some* meta/unhelpful/ambiguous tags from my corpus of tags, to get rid of *some* noise in my data. Shadow Wizard's suggestion basically provides what I need.

Comment: Burnination just means deleting the tag from all posts. The tag is then deleted and is no longer anywhere to *be* listed. The tag blacklist is not public, it is fairly rare for a tag to be blacklisted.

Comment: You can just search the child meta site for burnination requests.